# How to get lookup field in Search REST API?

Tags: client-object-model, search-results, lookup-column, search-api

How to retrieve the lookupId or lookupvalue in Search REST API results with other fields. `http://server/_api/search/query?querytext='sharepoint'&selectproperties='Title,Age'`

Comment: You should be able to get the value by mapping the field as a managed property. But I'm not able to get the lookup id...